# sending one page/slide of a publication in Publisher as a PDF

Tags: email, microsoft-publisher

I update a calendar periodically in MS Publisher, and I want to send one slide of the calendar as a PDF but the only options are to send one slide in the body of the email or send the entire publication as a PDF. Do I have to copy and paste the entire slide into a new document and then send that one page as a PDF or is there a way to go around this issue? Please advise... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may already have a PDF printer installed.  If not, you can find a number of free ones online (PDFcreator is one).

In Publisher, go to File->Print and select the PDF printer.  Change the print range to the specific page you want.  When you hit "OK" you'll get a save dialog asking where to save the PDF.